# Deleting From Amazon S3

Tags: url, amazon-s3, cname

I have a (hopefully easy) question regarding Amazon S3 and Cloudfront.  I'm using S3Fox, and I have a CNAME setup to point to my bucket: http://mycname.mydomain.com

I've noticed that when I open/access that file via a distribution URL (my CNAME), and then, go to delete the file from the bucket later, the distribution URL still works.

When I delete a file from my bucket, and no longer want it to show up under my distribution URL, do I need to delete the distibution files somehow?  Or does it just take a while for those files to be deleted as well?

Any help on this would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes sometime for the file to be removed from edge locations. Usually 24 hours.